# Image map in rails don't work

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I maping on the page. When you move an object changes the picture (the effect of a simple painting field guidance + additional inscriptions have already been made in the image, which is the main replaced)
In page html in the works, and when you add in VIEV in rails app not working(not view image). 
How to add image map in rails app

```
<div>
  <p> <img id="map5" src="001_0.png" width="1200" height="480" usemap="#Navigationmap5"> </p>
  <p><map name="Navigationmap5">
    <area shape="poly" coords="293,415,395,414,522,416,524,448,433,451,433,456,388,456,343,457,259,461,229,458,175,456,176,423,227,417" href="#" title=""onmouseover="document.getElementById('map5').src='001_12.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('map5').src='001_0.png'">
    <area shape="poly" coords="164,399,164,410,222,400,233,399,242,399,259,399,276,399,291,398,522,402,522,390,292,383,274,385,259,385,243,385,226,385,165,398" href="#" title="" onmouseover="document.getElementById('map5').src='001_21.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('map5').src='001_0.png'" >
   </map></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is the hard-coded image-link here:

```
<img id="map5" src="001_0.png" width="1200" height="480" usemap="#Navigationmap5">
```

You can change that to an `image_tag` (and put your actual image in the assets/images folder)

```
<%= image_tag "001_0.png", :id => "map5", :width => "1200", :height => "480", :usemap => "#Navigationmap5" %>
```

or something like that.
Note: this has not been tested - you will need to check the rails docs and make sure it's correct.